# How to Extract my chosen emails from huge file

Tags: notepad++, emeditor

I have huge file with 300 milion records. On every line appers email adress with information.
Sometimes one email can appear up to 40 times.

I have a list of 15,000 email addresses and I would like to extract all of their occurrences from this database.

I already did .txt file with all emails then open in Emeditor. I used function

'''
/r/n replace with: |
'''

I had everything in format a@gmail.com|b@gmail.com|c@gmail.com

next step was bookmark all of them in this huge file, it working fine but too too slowly, do u have any ideas how to do it faster? maybe any scripts? another functions?

Comment: Write a script in your favorite scripting language it will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I believe the Import feature for Bulk Find will speed up this task.

If you open Batch Find, click Import, and open the list of 15,000 email addresses, you can find those email addresses in the email database. Import assumes that your email addresses are on separate lines.

[image]

You can then use Multi-Find Next to find instances, or you can Batch Bookmark, or you can also Batch Extract to get a new file with the matched emails.